# Kruskal-Katona question

Tags: combinatorics

Prove that,if $|\mathcal{A}|= \binom{x}{r}$, where $x∈\mathbb{R}$ and $x>r−1$, then $|∂A|> \binom{x}{r-1}$.

I think I'm supposed to use Kruskal Katona but don't know where to get started - any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does $\partial \mathcal{A}$ stand for?

Comment: The shadow of A